# React reconciliation - props diff

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am packing jQuery Flotchart component as a React one and I need to call `plot` method of a chart instance whenever the component properties change.

What I have end up with is `shouldComponentUpdate` hook implementation which compares new props with the old ones.

However the [React documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#dom-nodes) that React itself compares new component props to the old ones as a part of reconciliation process, so React already should have the information about whether some of the props changed. This means that if I perform shallow comparison of props in `shouldComponentUpdate`, I duplicate the functionality already built in React, is that right? If so, how do I get the information about whether the properties changed from React, without the need to duplicate it in `shouldComponentUpdate` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React does not do any shallow comparison of props, its provides component lifecycle hooks to add your logic inside *shouldComponentUpdate* based on props ot state or your custom logic. However, if your component is *pureComponent* react does shallow comparison for you based on props or state.

Whenever the props / state change react call couple of hook method before calling render function.

> componentWillReceiveProps() ---> shouldComponentUpdate() --->
>   componentWillUpdate() ---> render() ---> componentDidUpdate()

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `componentWillReceiveProps`. According to reactjs [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops), this method will receive the next set of component properties as `nextProps`.

You can compare the properties like

```
if (nextProps.myProperty === this.props.myProperty) {//doSomething}
```